# Sistema de abas em CSS para de funcionar ao mudar quantidade

Tags: html, css

Estou tentando usar um sistema de abas em CSS puro. Pareceu muito bom, porém quando adiciono novas abas ou removo alguma ele para de funcionar, alguém sabe me falar o porque?

Só com 3 abas funciona bem:

```css
.tabs input[type='radio'] { 
    display:none 
}
.tabs label {
    width:100px; 
    text-align:center; 
    padding: 20px;
    color:#666666; 
    display:inline-block;
    cursor:pointer;
}
.tab-content { 
    display:none; 
    background-color:#F3F3F3; 
    border-top:6px #FE7B43 solid;  
    text-align:center; 
    padding:50px 0; 
    position:relative; 
}
#tabs-1 :checked + * + * + label { background-color:#FE7B43; color:#FFF; }
#tabs-1 :checked + * + * + * + * + * + .tab-content { display: block }
```

```html
 <div class="tabs" id="tabs-1">
                
                <input id="tab-1-1" name="tabs-group-1" type="radio" checked />
                <input id="tab-1-2" name="tabs-group-1" type="radio" />
                <input id="tab-1-3" name="tabs-group-1" type="radio" />

                <label for="tab-1-1">ABA 1</label>
                <label for="tab-1-2">ABA 2</label>
                <label for="tab-1-3">ABA 3</label>

                <!-- Aba 1 -->
                <div class="tab-content">
                    asdasdasdasdasd<br><br>dfasdfsadfasdfasdasdasdasdasd<br><br>dfasdfsadfasdfasdasdasdasdasd<br><br>dfasdfsadfasdf
                </div>

                <!-- Aba 2 -->
                <div class="tab-content">
                    CONTEUDO ABA 2
                </div>

                <!-- Aba 3 -->
                <div class="tab-content">
                    CONTEUDO ABA 3
                </div>

            </div>
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

A arquitetura desse CSS não é das melhores na hora da manutenção, pois ela depende da quantidade de elementos intermediários pra cada aba. Se gerar dinamicamente, com uma linguagem server-side tudo bem, mas para atualizar manualmente, precisa estar bem "inteirado" do funcionamento.

Antes de mais nada, veja funcionando com 4 abas:

```css
.tabs input[type='radio'] { 
    display:none 
}
.tabs label {
    width:100px; 
    text-align:center; 
    padding: 20px;
    color:#666666; 
    display:inline-block;
    cursor:pointer;
}
.tab-content { 
    display:none; 
    background-color:#F3F3F3; 
    border-top:6px #FE7B43 solid;  
    text-align:center; 
    padding:50px 0; 
    position:relative; 
}
#tabs-1 :checked + * + * + * + label { background-color:#FE7B43; color:#FFF; }
#tabs-1 :checked + * + * + * + * + * + * + * + .tab-content { display: block }
```

```html
<div class="tabs" id="tabs-1">
                
                <input id="tab-1-1" name="tabs-group-1" type="radio" checked />
                <input id="tab-1-2" name="tabs-group-1" type="radio" />
                <input id="tab-1-3" name="tabs-group-1" type="radio" />
                <input id="tab-1-4" name="tabs-group-1" type="radio" />

                <label for="tab-1-1">ABA 1</label>
                <label for="tab-1-2">ABA 2</label>
                <label for="tab-1-3">ABA 3</label>
                <label for="tab-1-4">ABA 4</label>

                <!-- Aba 1 -->
                <div class="tab-content">
                    asdasdasdasdasd<br><br>dfasdfsadfasdfasdasdasdasdasd<br><br>dfasdfsadfasdfasdasdasdasdasd<br><br>dfasdfsadfasdf
                </div>

                <!-- Aba 2 -->
                <div class="tab-content">
                    CONTEUDO ABA 2
                </div>

                <!-- Aba 3 -->
                <div class="tab-content">
                    CONTEUDO ABA 3
                </div>

                <!-- Aba 4 -->
                <div class="tab-content">
                    CONTEUDO ABA 4
                </div>

            </div>
```

Pra funcionar, foram ajustadas estas linhas

```
#tabs-1 :checked + * + * + * + label { background-color:#FE7B43; color:#FFF; }
#tabs-1 :checked + * + * + * + * + * + * + * + .tab-content { display: block }
```

Um `+ *` a mais na primeira linha, pra cada aba, e dois na segunda linha.

Uma solução mais escalável seria colocar os checkboxes antes de cada aba, e usar o seletor `+` absoluto

### Refatorando para funcionar independente do número de abas

A técnica é a mesma, mas reordenei os campos e o CSS de forma a cada *radiobutton* estar sempre à mesma distância da sua respectiva aba e seu conteúdo. Para aumentar ou diminuir a quantidade de abas, basta replicar os blocos de `radio` + `label` + `div`.

O único cuidado é fazer com que todas as abas caibam na mesma linha.

```css
.tabs input[type='radio'] { 
    display:none;
    position:absolute;
    left:-100px;
}
.tabs label {
    width:60px; 
    text-align:center; 
    padding: 20px;
    color:#666666; 
    display:inline-block;
    cursor:pointer;
}
.tab-content { 
    display:none; 
    position:absolute;
    left:0;
    width:100%;
    background-color:#F3F3F3; 
    border-top:6px #FE7B43 solid;  
    text-align:center; 
    padding:50px 0; 
}
#tabs-1 {position:relative}
#tabs-1 :checked + label { background-color:#FE7B43; color:#FFF; }
#tabs-1 :checked + label + .tab-content { display: block }
```

```html
<div class="tabs" id="tabs-1">
  <input id="tab-1-1" name="tabs-group-1" type="radio" checked />
  <label for="tab-1-1">ABA 1</label>
  <div class="tab-content">
    CONTEUDO ABA 1
  </div>

  <input id="tab-1-2" name="tabs-group-1" type="radio" />
  <label for="tab-1-2">ABA 2</label>
  <div class="tab-content">
    CONTEUDO ABA 2
  </div>

  <input id="tab-1-3" name="tabs-group-1" type="radio" />
  <label for="tab-1-3">ABA 3</label>
  <div class="tab-content">
    CONTEUDO ABA 3
  </div>

  <input id="tab-1-4" name="tabs-group-1" type="radio" />
  <label for="tab-1-4">ABA 4</label>
  <div class="tab-content">
    CONTEUDO ABA 4
  </div>

  <input id="tab-1-5" name="tabs-group-1" type="radio" />
  <label for="tab-1-5">ABA 5</label>
  <div class="tab-content">
    CONTEUDO ABA 5
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 4):

Cada vez que você adicionar mais abas, vai precisar aumentar o numero de `* +` no `CSS` na parte:

```
#tabs-1 :checked + * + * + * + label {
  background-color: #FE7B43;
  color: #FFF;
}

#tabs-1 :checked + * + * +  * + * + * + * + * + .tab-content {
  display: block
}
```

```css
.tabs input[type='radio'] {
  display: none
}
.tabs label {
  width: 100px;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 20px;
  color: #666666;
  display: inline-block;
  cursor: pointer;
}
.tab-content {
  display: none;
  background-color: #F3F3F3;
  border-top: 6px #FE7B43 solid;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 50px 0;
  position: relative;
}
#tabs-1 :checked + * + * + * + label {
  background-color: #FE7B43;
  color: #FFF;
}
#tabs-1 :checked + * + * +  * + * + * + * + * + .tab-content {
  display: block
}
```

```html
<div class="tabs" id="tabs-1">
  <input id="tab-1-1" name="tabs-group-1" type="radio" checked />
  <input id="tab-1-2" name="tabs-group-1" type="radio" />
  <input id="tab-1-3" name="tabs-group-1" type="radio" />
  <input id="tab-1-4" name="tabs-group-1" type="radio" />
  <label for="tab-1-1">ABA 1</label>
  <label for="tab-1-2">ABA 2</label>
  <label for="tab-1-3">ABA 3</label>
  <label for="tab-1-4">ABA 4</label>
  <!-- Aba 1 -->
  <div class="tab-content">
    CONTEUDO ABA 1
  </div>
  <!-- Aba 2 -->
  <div class="tab-content">
    CONTEUDO ABA 2
  </div>
  <!-- Aba 3 -->
  <div class="tab-content">
    CONTEUDO ABA 3
  </div>
  <!-- Aba 4 -->
  <div class="tab-content">
    CONTEUDO ABA 4
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: tem como fazer isso de forma automática?usando jQuery?

Comment: +1 diagnosticamos praticamente ao mesmo tempo e a mesma coisa.

Comment: Yp @Bacco, só que a sua esta mais completa rs, eu pelo menos não saberia explicar o porque... vou excluir a minha resposta hausahs

Comment: @MarceloBonifazio não exclua não, tá valendo. A minha eu complementei mais no sentido de mostrar a alternativa. Deixe a sua, pois os votos são merecidos (e vc na verdade postou até um pouco antes da minha).